# animation freeze on mousemove (IE7 - IE8)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm stuck.
Yet 12h I'm trying to debug a weird problem. Thanks to IE7, IE8.

Here is a demo:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tDXdz/)

To get the issue, just look at the CSS and set the #container to `relative; marg. 0 auto` (That's what I need! ) Than hover #container and you'll see: mouseover = stops other .el animations!

I need here to have the `mouseover` event over the page (or #container) for the div `#mouse` to follow the pointer. And the div #container to be page-centered (not 100% width). The problem seemed so simple but it's weird!

1. when the div #mouse is not appended to the pointer - WORKS GREAT.
2. when less than 10 floating `.el` - GOOD. (bot not my solution, I need even up to 100+ .el.)
3. when #container is CSS set to `absolute` (when the container has 0px left/top)  - GREAT!

But I need it centered.

Please please help!

**EDITED:**
And yes, when the #container is set to `relative ; 0 auto`, and the `window` width is smaller than #container than the issue is gone! ... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, and I haven't tried to debug it particularly deeply.

I did find a somewhat crazy fix:

```
$("#container").mousemove(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){       
        $('#mouse').css({top: e.clientY -12 , left: e.clientX +50});
    },0);
});
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/tDXdz/4/ - fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/tDXdz/4/show/

You should probably use this fix for IE7/8 *only*, because it *might* reduce performance in other browsers, and they don't need the fix. Test it.

Comment: (works great your solution.) Well thirtydot. that's incredible, isn't it? But nice workaround! I'll put this into an `if` browser version <=8 and that's it (I hope). +1 and a big thanks for your effort!